# Инициализация null переменной в объявлении метода С# method(T arg = null)

Tags: c#

```
 public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
```

Совершенно не понимаю и не могу нагуглить строчку  `bool> canExecute = null`.
Пожалуйста , объясните или скиньте ссылку что почитать. Не понимаю что это означает.

Comment: А что именно не ясно? Если в метод не передаётся второй аргумент, то значение по дефолту будет null.. ... Это  в любой книге для начинающих написано

Comment: на всякий случай уточню, что тип аргумента `canExecute` - `Func<object, bool>` , а не `bool>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я  этого не знал. Теперь понял. В основном на metanit читаю все. Там не встречал такой конструкции. Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/191482   попробуйте что-то отсюда почитать

Comment: Можно вместо `Func<object, bool>` писать `Predicate<object>` это одно и то же.